# Gamma integrals

Tags: gamma-function, special-functions

Is anything known about these integrals? Textbook suggestions are welcome

\begin{equation*}
f(n,p)=\int_{x=-0.5}^p \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!} dx,
\end{equation*}

$n>0, p\le n+0.5$.

For instance, as $n$ grows $2^n-f(n,n+1/2)$ seems to be positive and monotonically decreasing...how would I find the limit?

```
ListPlot[Table[2^n - NIntegrate[n!/(x! (n - x)!), {x, -1/2, n + 1/2}], {n, Range[30]}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: The equation in your *Mathematica* code does not match the one in TeX. :)

Comment: To simplify things a bit, your $f(n,p)$ is $\int_{-1/2}^p \binom{n}{x}\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: good catch, fixed

Comment: You missed my hint: check your definition for $f(n,p)$

Comment: @J. M. : Is there a typo in the $p\le n$ condition, in the definition of $f(n,p)$ ? In your example $f(n,n+1/2)$, $p=n+1/2>n$.

Comment: Apparently, we have to wait for Yaroslav to confirm this.

Comment: ok changed it....btw restriction p<=n+1/2 is pretty arbitrary, I picked it simply because that range seemed interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full solution, but maybe enough for you to get a handle on the problem:

Using $\Gamma (x+1) = x \Gamma (x)$ and $\Gamma(x) \Gamma(1-x) = \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi x}$, one obtains
$$
\Gamma(x + 1) \Gamma(n - x + 1) = \frac{(-1)^n \pi}{\sin \pi x} \prod_{k=0}^{n} (x - k) .
$$
Thus,
$$
f(n, p) = \frac{(-1)^n n!}{\pi} \int_{-0.5}^p \frac{\sin \pi x}{\prod_{k=0}^n (x-k)} d x .
$$
Using partial fractions, you can now transform $f$ into a sum of values of the sine integral.

Addendum: Computing the sums yields
$$
f(n, n+\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} Si (\pi k + \frac{\pi}{2})
$$
Note, that $Si (x) = \frac{\pi}{2} + O(x^{- 2})$. However, I have no idea how to leverage this to find the limit.

Comment: That looks even nastier than the original.